# How to find what log4j classes are missing in the log4j bridge

Tags: log4j

I am working on a project that uses a lot of legacy libraries that use log4j. I was wondering that do all classes of log4j have support in the bridge (no-ops classes are fine, I am mostly concerned about ClassNotFoundException)? If not, Is there a list of classes that are not supported in the log4j bridge that I can go through to make sure that libraries are not using those. I am using 2.20 version of log4j bridge.

I tried looking at the docs and it just says that "applications that try to modify legacy Log4j by adding Appenders, Filters, etc, may experience problems" [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-1.2-api.html), I am not sure what that means? Does that mean these don't exist or are these no-ops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** There are a lot of binary incompatibilities between `log4j:log4j` and `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api`, but 99% of usages in libraries is covered. Besides most legacy libraries do not use `log4j:log4j` directly, but facades like `commons-logging:commons-logging`.

There are many ways to check API differences between versions. For example you can use [BND Baseline Maven plugin](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/tree/master/maven-plugins/bnd-baseline-maven-plugin).

To use it you need to:

- download and unpack the sources of [Log4j 2.22.1](https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/release/logging/log4j/2.22.1/),
- set `JAVA_HOME` to the path of a JDK 17 installation,
- run:

  ```
  sh mvnw package bnd-baseline:baseline \
    -DskipTests \
    -Dbnd.baseline.full.report -Dbnd.baseline.base.coordinates=log4j:log4j:1.2.17
  ```
- you'll get a full report in `log4j-1.2-api/target/baseline`.

The report (cf. [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ppkarwasz/9fcc1daedd34adda3fd48bb195d1bda0)) contains the full account of public API changes, e.g.:

```
        REMOVED        CLASS      org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender
...
        MAJOR          CLASS      org.apache.log4j.Category
          REMOVED      FIELD      resourceBundle
            REMOVED    ACCESS     protected
            REMOVED    RETURN     java.util.ResourceBundle
...
        REMOVED        CLASS      org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
...
        MAJOR          CLASS      org.apache.log4j.LogManager
          ADDED        ACCESS     final
```

As you can see, there are a lot of differences. The reason behind this is that the scope of `log4j-1.2-api` is not to provide 100% binary compatibility but:

- to provide 100% compatibility in the public methods of the "API" classes (`Category`, `LogManager`, `Level`, `Logger`, etc.), which is what most library (should) use,
- to provide 100% compatibility for programmatic configuration classes, such as [`PropertyConfigurator`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html),
- to provide some compatibility for custom appenders and layouts, to allow users time to drop those components in favor of original Log4j 2.x Core components or rewrite them.